# How to make a confirm box that dowloads an image when you press 'Okay' (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, download, confirm

```html
<a id="cat" href="Images/virusKat.jpg" download="whitey"></a>
<button onclick="sickcat()">download picture of cat </button>

<script>
  function sickcat() {
    var choice = confirm("warning! this adorable cat has a virus! dont wanna get sick");
    if (choice == true) {
      document.getElementById("cat").download
    } else {
      //cancel
    }
  }
</script>
```

I'm doing a little joke web page for IT class because we're learning Javascript.

Here's what I want to happen: when you click the button it pops up a confirm box (which works) but then when you click confirm (or okay) it's meant to download the image but nothing happens. Why doesn't the image download?

Comment: Nothing happens at all?

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS nothing unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For one you can just make a button with the a href tag inside of it to download. If you need the confirmation, you can just call the click method on the href.

```
<a id="cat" href="Images/virusKat.jpg" download="whitey"></a>
<button onclick="sickcat()">download picture of cat </button>
<script>
function sickcat() {
var choice = confirm("warning! this adorable cat has a virus! dont wanna get sick");
if (choice == true) {
    document.getElementById("cat").click()
} else {
    //cancel
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: ive tried this one previously, it just pops up the picture but it doesnt download anything. thanks still though!

Comment: It works for me. I think you have probably messed up something in your system. Check the file path. Try replacing the file path with an image address like google or something. Copy image address and paste it in and tell me if it works then.

Comment: it still doesnt work! crazy.. I even tried adding a jquery to see if maybe I was missing any libraries but nothing worked.

Comment: What if you just paste the code into a webpage like google.com or something and try it there. Maybe it is something with your editor. Maybe javascript is blocked on your browser?